# How to limit User to select upto 5 selections in angular material design <mat-select multiple>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to allow the user to select not more than 5 selection in `<mat-select multiple>`, how will I achieve that.

Event `selectionChange` I used but, was not able to reflect  UI for blocking user in the selection, not more than 5.

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="orderSearchModel.analystId" name="analyst"  (selectionChange)="onChangeAnalyst($event)" multiple>
    <mat-option (click)="clearAnalyst()">clear</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.value" >{{user.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I expect user should not be allowed to select not more than 5 selection in my `multi-select`.

Answer (score 8):

This is fairly simple assuming that your `[(ngModel)]="orderSearchModel.analystId"` is an array of selected elements - which it should be if you use `multiple`. (Make sure to change your naming to plural, because it's a bit confusing now `orderSearchModel.analystId > orderSearchModel.analystIds`)

You can add this `[disabled]` property to your second `<mat-option>` and if you don't use `selectionChange()` for anything else, you can remove it.

```
[disabled]="orderSearchModel?.analystId.length >= 5 && !orderSearchModel.analystId.includes(user.value)"
```

The first check is looking at how many elements are currently selected.

The second check is making sure to disable only the elements which are not yet selected.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanx